# Displaying the entered values of dynamically generated input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form and the user is able to dynamically add multiple address sections for entering their different office locations. Once the form is complete, the user is able to "preview" the information they have entered. I am able to show the data entered into the original address section. However, I need to show the data entered into the dynamically generated address sections, as well. How would I go about displaying the information they have entered into the newly generated address section(s)?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Variables
  var x = 0;
  var address = document.getElementById('inputAddress');
  var address2 = document.getElementById('inputAddress2');
  var city = document.getElementById('inputCity');
  var state = document.getElementById('state');
  var zip = document.getElementById('inputZip');
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone');
  var cell = document.getElementById('cell');
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var fax = document.getElementById('fax');

  //Add another address section
  $('#add_location_btn').click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    appendLocation(); // Append New Form Section
    x++; // Increment Counter
  });

  //Construct and append the new address section
  let appendLocation = () => {
    $('#location_wrapper').append(
      '<section class="location-section">' +
      '<hr>' +
      '<div class="form-row">' +
      '<div class="form-group col-sm-12">' +
      '<button type="button" id="delete-location-btn-' +
      x +
      '" class="btn btn-danger deleteBtn shadow-none float-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete Location</i></button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-row">' +
      '<div class="form-group col-sm-12">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="inputAddress1-' +
      x +
      '">Address1</label>' +
      '<input type="text" id="inputAddress1-' +
      x +
      '" class="form-control location" name="inputAddress1-' +
      x +
      '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-row">' +
      '<div class="form-group col-sm-12">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="inputAddress2-' +
      x +
      '">Address2</label>' +
      '<input type="text" id="inputAddress2-' +
      x +
      '" class="form-control location" name="inputAddress2-' +
      x +
      '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-row">' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-6">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="inputCity-' +
      x +
      '">City</label>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control location" id="inputCity-' +
      x +
      '" name="inputCity' +
      x +
      '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-4">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="state-' +
      x +
      '">State</label>' +
      '<select id="state-' +
      x +
      '" class="custom-select location" name="state-' +
      x +
      '">' +
      "<option selected>filler state</option>" +
      "</select>" +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-2">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="inputZip-' + x + '">Zip</label>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control location" id="inputZip-' + x + '" name="inputZip-' + x + '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-row">' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-3">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="phone-' + x + '">Phone</label>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control location" id="phone-' + x + '" name="phone-' + x + '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-3">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="cell-' + x + '">Cell</label>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control location" id="cell-' + x + '" name="cell-' + x + '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-3">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="email-' +
      x +
      '">Email</label>' +
      '<input type="email" class="form-control location" id="email-' +
      x +
      '" name="email-' +
      x +
      '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-3">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="fax-' +
      x +
      '">Fax</label>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control location" id="fax-' +
      x +
      '" name="fax-' +
      x +
      '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</section>'
    )
  };

  // Remove sections and button control
  $('#location_wrapper').on('click', '.deleteBtn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // find div and delete based on the closest parent section
    $(this)
      .closest('section, deleteBtn')
      .remove();
    // decrement the counter for form.
    x--;
  });

  //Preview the entered data, prior to submission
  $('#preview_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('displayAddress1').innerText = address.value
    document.getElementById('displayAddress2').innerText = address2.value
    document.getElementById('displayCity').innerText = city.value
    document.getElementById('displayState').innerText = state.value
    document.getElementById('displayZip').innerText = zip.value
    document.getElementById('displayPhone').innerText = phone.value
    document.getElementById('displayCell').innerText = cell.value
    document.getElementById('displayEmail').innerText = email.value
    document.getElementById('displayFax').innerText = fax.value
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="previewModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="profilePreview" aria-describedby="Profile Preview" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Profile Preview</h5>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button> -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">Address:</div>
            <div class="col-md-9 ml-auto">
              <span id="displayAddress1"></span>
              <br>
              <span id="displayAddress2"></span>
              <br>
              <span id="displayCity"></span>
              <span id="displayState"></span>
              <span id="displayZip"></span>
              <br>
              <div id="dynamicAddress"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">Phone:</div>
            <div class="col-md-9 ml-auto"><span id="displayPhone"></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Cell:</div>
            <div class="col-md-9 ml-auto"><span id="displayCell"></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Email:</div>
            <div class="col-md-9 ml-auto"><span id="displayEmail"></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Fax:</div>
            <div class="col-md-9 ml-auto"><span id="displayFax"></span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="acceptProfile" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Accept</button>
        <button type="button" id="rejectProfile" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Reject</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form name="addProfileForm" id="addProfileForm">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-card">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h4>Enter Office Locations</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" name="inputAddress">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" name="inputAddress2">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="inputCity">City</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" name="inputCity">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <select id="state" class="custom-select location" name="state">
              <option selected>Test State</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" name="inputZip">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="cell">Cell</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cell" name="cell">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="fax">Fax</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fax" name="fax">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="location_wrapper"></div>
      <div class='form-row'>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" id="add_location_btn" class="btn btn-primary shadow-none float-right">Add
                    Location</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="button" id="preview_button" class="btn btn-primary shadow-none mr-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewModal">Preview</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Your snippet does not work. You do not have displayAddress1 or displayAddress2

Comment: Ha!... My apologies. I'll edit and repost. Thank you.

Comment: Also please investigate clone. It is very inelegant to mix DOM (document.getElement...) and jQuery and then build the HTML from strings. At least look at template literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way

```
  $('#preview_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const preview = $(":input").map(function() {
      return `${this.name}:${this.value}` 
    }).get().join('<br/>')
    $("body").append(preview);
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Variables
  var x = 0;
  var address = document.getElementById('inputAddress');
  var address2 = document.getElementById('inputAddress2');
  var city = document.getElementById('inputCity');
  var state = document.getElementById('state');
  var zip = document.getElementById('inputZip');
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone');
  var cell = document.getElementById('cell');
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var fax = document.getElementById('fax');

  //Add another address section
  $('#add_location_btn').click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    appendLocation(); // Append New Form Section
    x++; // Increment Counter
  });

  //Construct and append the new address section
  let appendLocation = () => {
    $('#location_wrapper').append(
      '<section class="location-section">' +
      '<hr>' +
      '<div class="form-row">' +
      '<div class="form-group col-sm-12">' +
      '<button type="button" id="delete-location-btn-' +
      x +
      '" class="btn btn-danger deleteBtn shadow-none float-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete Location</i></button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-row">' +
      '<div class="form-group col-sm-12">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="inputAddress1-' +
      x +
      '">Address1</label>' +
      '<input type="text" id="inputAddress1-' +
      x +
      '" class="form-control location" name="inputAddress1-' +
      x +
      '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-row">' +
      '<div class="form-group col-sm-12">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="inputAddress2-' +
      x +
      '">Address2</label>' +
      '<input type="text" id="inputAddress2-' +
      x +
      '" class="form-control location" name="inputAddress2-' +
      x +
      '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-row">' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-6">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="inputCity-' +
      x +
      '">City</label>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control location" id="inputCity-' +
      x +
      '" name="inputCity' +
      x +
      '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-4">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="state-' +
      x +
      '">State</label>' +
      '<select id="state-' +
      x +
      '" class="custom-select location" name="state-' +
      x +
      '">' +
      "<option selected>filler state</option>" +
      "</select>" +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-2">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="inputZip-' + x + '">Zip</label>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control location" id="inputZip-' + x + '" name="inputZip-' + x + '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-row">' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-3">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="phone-' + x + '">Phone</label>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control location" id="phone-' + x + '" name="phone-' + x + '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-3">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="cell-' + x + '">Cell</label>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control location" id="cell-' + x + '" name="cell-' + x + '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-3">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="email-' +
      x +
      '">Email</label>' +
      '<input type="email" class="form-control location" id="email-' +
      x +
      '" name="email-' +
      x +
      '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group col-md-3">' +
      '<div class="field">' +
      '<label for="fax-' +
      x +
      '">Fax</label>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control location" id="fax-' +
      x +
      '" name="fax-' +
      x +
      '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</section>'
    )
  };

  // Remove sections and button control
  $('#location_wrapper').on('click', '.deleteBtn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // find div and delete based on the closest parent section
    $(this)
      .closest('section, deleteBtn')
      .remove();
    // decrement the counter for form.
    x--;
  });

  //Preview the entered data, prior to submission
  $('#preview_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const preview = $(":input").map(function() {
      return `${this.name}:${this.value}` 
    }).get().join('<br/>')
    $("body").append(preview);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="addProfileForm" id="addProfileForm">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-card">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h4>Enter Office Locations</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" name="inputAddress">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" name="inputAddress2">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="inputCity">City</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" name="inputCity">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <select id="state" class="custom-select location" name="state">
              <option selected>Test State</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" name="inputZip">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="cell">Cell</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cell" name="cell">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="fax">Fax</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fax" name="fax">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="location_wrapper"></div>
      <div class='form-row'>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" id="add_location_btn" class="btn btn-primary shadow-none float-right">Add
                    Location</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="button" id="preview_button" class="btn btn-primary shadow-none mr-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewModal">Preview</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```